# Interactive features of PDF

Tags: pdf

I've been playing around lately with pdf layers/ocg (optional content groups) to create some interactivity in pdf documents used for teaching. Until recently I was not even aware that pdf could do such.

Are there any other cool features of pdf files that could be used in a similar context (interactive teaching) and that can be created through LaTeX?